# Qual a diferença entre forms.Form e forms.ModelForm?

Tags: python-3.x, django, formulário

Olá, prezados.

Com a ajuda de um tutorial, consegui criar um template com formulário e utilizar o forms.ModelForm para salvar no banco, porém, vi na documentação do Django que existe também o forms.Form. Qual a diferença?

framework Django1.9
Python3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A diferença é simples, o [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/) serve para criar o formulário de um Model.

```
# Formulário que salva artigos no seu banco de dados.
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Artigo
        fields = ['pub_date', 'headline', 'content', 'reporter']
```

Já o [Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/) é um formulário comum que não tem relação com seu banco de dados (model).

```
# formulário de contato para enviar via e-mail
class ContatoForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Answer (score 0):

Exatamente como foi dito acima p ModelForm liga o seu Model ao Banco de Dados, já o Form realiza a conexão do Model com a Interface, as Views e Templates.